# Javascript linking to other pages

Tags: javascript, dynamic, web, traffic

We're running over a problem here. We have a website which shows a header, content and a footer. Now, when clicking on a link we want just a part of the site (content-part) to be refreshed to save some traffic. The header and footer should stay as they're. We tried to use the following script for that:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm

Well, the script is not doing great on our site. Any other JS-Code does not get executed at all. The GET-Tags in the URL are not displayed aswell. Everything else works with that script.

Do you have knowledge about any other alternatives to this script?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I agree, Ajax is the way.
You can include jQuery.

Have a look at these links.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

In particular  jquery load() function

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');
```

a little  jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/james_nicholson/c6dpn/5/

please note:     `$("#content").load("a/html/page/that/should/be/on/your/server");`

.load(); <- needs to have  a local page, PHP and or HTML will do.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'Any other JS-Code does not get executed at all', do you mean at any time from when the page loads initially, or only when the content part is refreshed?

Comment: any from the beinning, except for the script linked above

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic adjustment in javascript i would recommend http://angularjs.org/ or http://knockoutjs.com/ , try this out and work through tutorials and you will see how easy it is to change everything without refreshing.

I'd say you only need AJAX if you get some data from a database. Otherwise it's enough to work with AngularJS or KnockoutJS. Have a look at it!

Regards